# laravel: looping images folder with index value

Tags: php, laravel

[image]i am trying to show an image from the images folder however the image is not showing although i am able to see it in an array if i die and dump the "$image". The images are located in "public/images" folder

### blade file

```
<div class="gallery"> 
            @foreach($posts as $post)
           <div class="round-post">
               @foreach ($post->images as $image)
               <a href="/images/{{$image[0]}}"  data-lightbox='lo'> <img src="/images/{{$image[0]}}"  data-lightbox='lo'class = "img-posts" alt=""> </a>
             
                 ........

               @endforeach
            
            @endforeach
        </div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

when i `<img src="/images/ <?php dd($image[0]);` i get
[image]

Comment: use `<img src="{{asset('image_full_path_from_public_folder')}}">`

Comment: What the output of `<img src="/images/ <?php dd($image[0]); ?>`?

Comment: @STA there is the output for that code

Comment: Can you give me the output here?

Comment: @STA it brings a bunch of text with "null" at the bottom of it. i captured the text and added it in the question above.

Comment: Do you see the image,  if you write the path name as  `<img src="/images/image.png" data-lightbox='lo' class = "img-posts" alt="">`???

Comment: @STA yes that way the image is showing

Comment: Post this output only `<?php dd($image[0]); ?>` here

Comment: @STA  it brings an image like thing  with "null" on the bottom

Comment: replace $image[0] with $image->image

Answer (score 0):

this bunch of code get your images that exist in your images folder:

```
public function index(){

    $images = \File::allFiles(public_path('images'));

    return View('pages.form')->with(array('images'=>$images));

}
```

this will show the images in your blade.

```
            <ul>
            @foreach ($images as $image)
                 <li style="width:80px;display:inline-block;margin:5px 0px">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="{{$image->getFilename()}}"/>
                     <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}" width="50" height="50">
                 </li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
```

for more information you can read this [article](https://dev.to/skipperhoa/show-all-image-from-public-folder-using-laravel-5-8-3a02).

Good luck my friend!